# How can I see statistics for a Google Slides presentation?

Tags: analytics, google-slides

Specifically, I'd like to see the amount of visits that it gets and the geographic region. Searching in Google it looks like it was possible at some point but for the life of me I can't find it in the interface.

Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 2):

At this time Google Slides doesn't include a visits tracking feature so instead of sharing the presentation URL directly, embed a presentation in a web site or use a URL shortener that offer you the statistics that you need.

I.E. You could add your presentation easily to a site in [Google Sites](http://sites.google.com) with which you could use [Google Analytics](https://analytics.google.com/) for visits tracking. A simpler tool that could be good enough is Google URL Shortener, aka http://goo.gl

Comment: Any shortener that is free and has analytics?

Answer (score 0):

Have been struggling with the lack of analytics on my presentations for ages.

Agree with other suggestions of connecting Google Analytics to a copy of your presentation posted online via a Google Site.

Unfortunately, that model means you have to do a custom setup for every presentation, and the statistics you get are quite high level. If you want to get deeper visitor tracking and be able to identify them, you can [check out this tool](https://superslide.co) that I came across recently.

They've just [posted on their blog](https://superslide.substack.com/p/analytics-for-google-slides-presentations) with a side by side comparison of the GA/GTM approach and their own tool. Check it out.